# Drop shadow will not go away

Tags: wordpress, css

I have been working with a WordPress site and I am having an issue removing the drop shadow in the header. I was able to remove the header background color and to position it how I want but I can not get the drop shadow to go away.I used this css code:

```
#insta-header {
    background: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    position: relative;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

but when I save and view the page the drop shadow is still there. If I inspect the element it shows my coding and the original coding. The web site is at http://www.clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/ . Any ideas how I can remove the drop shadow once and for all?

Comment: If I had to guess, without looking through the whole css file, you are changing it in one of the places that #insta-header is defined but not in all of them. It looks like at lines 22, 111, and 466 in your CSS file #insta-header is being declared. Try taking it down to only one or two and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add !important to force the override

```
#insta-header {
    background: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    position: relative;
    -ms-box-shadow: none !important;
    -o-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using `!important`, unless absolutely necessary. In this case the same result is achievable without using `!important`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Adding the !important forced the css to be accepted.

Comment: There is no reason to use `!important` in this scenario.

Comment: @PattyBelloise by forcing the css to be accepted, you also make it impossible to over-ride, for example, when you (or a 3rd party library) try to tweak something with javascript, or you (or a colleague) need to change things in one case six months down the line, I only use important if I need to over-ride an inline style added by code I have no control over

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `!important`, just increase specificity:

```
#container #insta-header {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Screenshot:

https://clbin.com/xOvIZO.png

In some environments you are forced into overwriting theme CSS, not sure if that is the case here or not. If you have access to all the CSS, remove the `box-shadow` styling from the other area where `#insta-header` is styled (that would be the best option).

Comment: I was actually typing something similar. I've been trying to get better at trying to not use `!important` where just crafting better selectors will do just fine. Before resorting to `!important`, make sure to understand why the style isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the other answers to override the box-shadow style.

But to remove it once and for all, you need to edit your "style.css" file. Starting on line 22 you have the following code.

```
 #insta-header{position:relative;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0,OffY=0,Color=#66000000,Positive=true)";filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=0, Color=#66000000, Positive=true)}
```

If you remove that line, that should get rid of it for you.

Comment: Access to the main style sheet is not granted to me which is why I was having the problem. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to find the declaration in the stylesheet that you are failing to over-ride and working around that. You might find a declaration which is over-reaching and you can then modify it so it only effects what it should, then you won't have to do any over-riding in the id you're trying to target.

The lazy solution is to use `!important` but you'll pay for that in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You could all this to the top of your stylesheet to remove all box-shadows (adding other browser prefixes as well):

```
*{ box-shadow: none !important; }
```

Comment: all this will do is fill the style-sheet full of extra importants where box-shadow is required - nuking your entire stylesheet with a declaration like this is not a good idea, maintenance will be horrendous